# Draw the profile of a scatter plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a scatter plot of Lc and Fc values (please, refer to plot1).

```
Lc= [360.66832393 388.26294316 392.9410819  ... 384.31751584 403.52581547
 384.22929343]

Fc= [77.3294787  47.5926941  44.53032575 ... 50.44012265 38.99666318
 50.54763385]

plot.scatter(Lc, Fc)
```

I would like to draw the Fc profile of this scatter plot as shown in plot2. Does anyone have an efficient way to do it?

[image: plot1]

[image: plot2]

Comment: One possible way could be by first creating a histogram with small bins and then using the bars to draw a line through the center of the bins at the top (however I am not 100% sure if it will work, there could be a scalling issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea drawing a Gaussian curve through each of the points and then take the maximum of these curves. You might want to experiment with the curve widths.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

low_lim = 30
fc = np.random.rand(120) * np.random.rand(120) * 120
fc = fc[fc > low_lim]
lc = np.random.uniform(50, 250, len(fc))

x = np.linspace(0, 300, 5000)
sigma = 15
ys = np.exp(- np.power((x.reshape(-1, 1) - lc) / sigma, 2) / 2) * fc
ymax = ys.max(axis=1)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(15, 4))
for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    if ax == ax1:
        ax.plot(x, ymax, color='black', ls=':', lw=3)
        for l, f, y in zip(lc, fc, ys.T):
            ax.plot(x, y)
            ax.fill_between(x, 0, y, color='r', alpha=0.05)
    else:
        ax.plot(x, ymax, color='black', lw=2)
        ax.fill_between(x, 0, ymax, color='r', alpha=0.2)
    ax.scatter(lc, fc, color='darkorange')
    ax.axhline(low_lim, ls='--', color='skyblue')
    ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
    ax.margins(x=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Gaussians through points and taking maximum]

Here is an attempt to smooth out the sharp corners, which might or might not work with your data. The effect is only very local; trying to smooth out more resulted in also losing the general shape.

```py
from scipy.special import softmax

ys = np.exp(- np.power((x.reshape(-1, 1) - lc) / sigma, 2) / 2) * fc
softmax_weights = softmax(np.power(ys, 0.8), axis=1)
ymax = np.sum(ys * softmax_weights, axis=1)
```

[image: smoothed out maximum of corners]

Comment: This approach is not very suitable for me as you have always to give it a sigma. Is these a way of doing this by dividing the data into bins and taking the max of each bin while moving in the x-axis ? Thank you

Comment: To divide into bins you also need to choose a bin width, for example 2 sigma.  This is quite similar to choosing `sigma = total_width / num_bins / 2`. Dividing into bins would generate strange artifacts; too much special cases would need handling. The maxima of adjacent bins could be close together.  Also, the second largest of a bin could be outside the curve of the maximum.